# Mysql informar cambios en bd a app java

Tags: java, mysql, eventos

Existe alguna manera de que cuando en una tabla se inserta determinado valor ejemplo estado: positivo o negativo "avisar", y no tener que desde la aplicación estar cada x tiempo haciendo una consulta?

Comment: Para MySQL, no hay forma de que la base de datos notifique a la aplicación si es que ha sufrido cambios. Hay bases de datos como Oracle que sí lo soportan. Si es una alternativa viable para tu proyecto, podrías utilizar [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com)

Comment: No me va a ser posible mudar a rethink, la bd es cargada por una raspberry en la que corre un desarrollo en lazarus, son varias las raspy q reportan a esta bd, la idea es que cuando haya un positivo o negativo saberlo, y enviar una notificación a un cliente android, q consume un servicio rest.

Comment: Entonces no te queda más que hacer poll (consultar cada cierto tiempo) a tu base de datos MySQL. Podrías quizás utilizar alguna estrategia con un trigger en tu tabla para que se ejecute un comando en el servidor que haga que se notifique a la aplicación pero es muy peligroso si no sabes bien lo que estás haciendo, podrías dispararte en tus pies en caso de un mal uso y posiblemente dejes abierta una puerta trasera a ataques, pero es otra opción.

Comment: Explicame un poco más esta opción,he usado trigger y storedpro...pero sólo para actualizar otras tablas

Comment: Puedes encontrar una mejor explicación aquí: [Triggering a shell script from MySQL](https://patternbuffer.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/triggering-shell-script-from-mysql/) y una pregunta/respuesta asociada a SO aquí: [Invoking a PHP script from a MySQL trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1467369/1065197) donde se explica en más detalle la idea que te propongo (por lo que veo a otras personas se les ocurrió esta locura antes que a mí [lo cual no me sorprende tanto] y la hicieron "funcionar").

Comment: Bueno, veré estas opciones. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

para no tener que preguntarle cada rato al servido, es mejor que el nos de el aviso, lo ideal es con node.js para eso, para java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991141/what-is-the-the-wcf-correspondent-for-java

Comment: Está bien que publiques un link a [so], pero ¿podrás explicar dentro de tu respuesta los puntos clave para solucionarlo?

Comment: Mmmm quizás no me explique bien, la la idea es que en base a un cambio en la bd enviar un notificacio  a una app Android, te aclaro esto por que en el hilo que me linkeas hablan sobre jax ws y yo tengo implementado jax rs para que lo consuma el cliente android.

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con lo que se pregunta.